# Media files fail Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-settings

I have a common problem with medias. I have a model which save an image in the media folder :

```
class Article(models.Model):
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    auteur = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    contenu = models.TextField(null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date")
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/media/upload/photos/", default="default.jpg")
```

But in my template when I try to get my picture by this way :

```
<img class="photo" src="{{ media_url }} {{ article.photo }}">
```

the {{ media_url }} is blank !

In my settings.py file I tried different configuration (found on this website), actually this is :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
#MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/blog/media/'
#MEDIA_ROOT = '/blog/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/remi/perso/django/projets/SiteBlog/blog/media/'

ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'static'),
)
```

It works well for static files but not at all for media files.

I also tried to add in urls.py this :

```
#    urlpatterns += patterns('',
#    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
#    'document_root' : settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

But with ths I get an "Syntax error".

Sorry to post for a common problem like that but I didn't find any working solution for me !

Thanks !

Rémi.

Comment: Are you doing this in a development or a deployment server? Some hosting services like Heroku can give you problems when retrieving images from the media folder.

Comment: @Phob1a I'm doing this in development with the "manage.py runserver" !

Answer (score 0):

Fitst change `{{ media_url }}` with `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` in your template.

```
<img class="photo" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }} {{ article.photo }}">
```

And change `urls.py` like this:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    # static files (images, css, javascript, etc.)
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.

if I change it in blog/urls.py (blog is my application) django throw me a syntax exception, but if I put it in Siteblog/urls.py (my project) he tells me nothing but still doesn't work.

In my Siteblog/urls.py I juste have 
`urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
)`

Comment: You do import "settings" correct? What is the Syntax Exception message?

Comment: @halfnibble yes I import correctly and the exception message is :

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/blog/article/14/
Django Version:  1.8
Exception Type:  SyntaxError
Exception Value:  

invalid syntax (urls.py, line 17)

Exception Location:  /usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py in import_module, line 37
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:  2.7.6


it means just there is a syntax error on ´urlpatterns += ... ´

Comment: Syntax error. Interesting. Can you post your entire urls.py file? And Django 1.8? I didn't even know that was out! I'm still using 1.6!!

Comment: @halfnibble I posted a new response with more infos, the syntay error is solved but it's always not working ! 1.8 version is the last I think